# Android: ArrayList old entries overwritten by new entry

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm retrieving information about places from my database. After retreiving them, I want to store them into an ArrayList (which is "ArrayList of Places", however, each time a new entry is written, it overwrites the previous entries too. I'm testing it out by printing the log. Below is the segment of codes:

```
response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://www.testing.com
/requestPlaces.php", postParameters);

            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);

            for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length() ; i++)
            {
                Places place = new Places();
                JSONObject jObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                place.setPlace(
                        jObj.optString("placeID"), 
                        jObj.optString("placeName"), 
                        jObj.optString("placeType"),
                        jObj.optString("placeLat"),
                        jObj.optString("placeLng"),
                        jObj.optString("placePict"),
                        jObj.optString("placeRegion"));

                arrPlace.add(place);
                for(int j = 0; j <= i ; j++)
                {
                    Log.e("log_tag2", arrPlace.get(j).getPlaceID());
                }
```

This is what my log prints out that shows that the previous entry has been overwritten:

```
02-22 16:30:26.538: E/log_tag2(6148): p0001
02-22 16:30:26.538: E/log_tag(6148): p0002
02-22 16:30:26.538: E/log_tag2(6148): p0002
02-22 16:30:26.538: E/log_tag2(6148): p0002
02-22 16:30:26.538: E/log_tag(6148): p0003
02-22 16:30:26.538: E/log_tag2(6148): p0003
02-22 16:30:26.538: E/log_tag2(6148): p0003
02-22 16:30:26.538: E/log_tag2(6148): p0003
02-22 16:30:26.538: E/log_tag(6148): p0004
02-22 16:30:26.538: E/log_tag2(6148): p0004
02-22 16:30:26.538: E/log_tag2(6148): p0004
02-22 16:30:26.538: E/log_tag2(6148): p0004
02-22 16:30:26.538: E/log_tag2(6148): p0004
```

Comment: It seems some kind of problem on the setPlace method, or at the scope of the properties wrote by this method. Could you please add the Places class code?

Comment: Thanks, its solved. Silly little thing! Lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would guess that you have `static` fields instead of instance fields in your `Places` class. Remove the `static` modifier:

```
class Places {
    static int id;
}
```

E.g:

```
class Places {
    int id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you also want to keep the loop of logging out side the loop where you add to list.

```
for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length() ; i++)
      {
                Places place = new Places();
                JSONObject jObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                place.setPlace(
                        jObj.optString("placeID"), 
                        jObj.optString("placeName"), 
                        jObj.optString("placeType"),
                        jObj.optString("placeLat"),
                        jObj.optString("placeLng"),
                        jObj.optString("placePict"),
                        jObj.optString("placeRegion"));

                arrPlace.add(place);
                 }
                for(int j = 0; j <= i ; j++)
                {
                    Log.e("log_tag2", arrPlace.get(j).getPlaceID());
                }
```